# How can I use macro expansion for the first identifier of a pragma?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, c-preprocessor, pragma

If I wanted to define the first identifier of a pragma how would I do this?

For example, I need something like this to work as an openmp pragma:

```
#define FOO omp
#pragma FOO parallel
```

So I need this to be interpreted as:

```
#pragma omp parallel
```

I'm using GCC in Linux. From what I've read so far it looks like this isn't supported. Is there any sort of workaround?

Comment: I don't think the preprocessor processes pragmas, meaning there is no way to do what you want.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Isn't `#pragma` a pre-processor directive just like `#define` or `#include`.Is **everything** about it compiler-dependent?The pre-processor ignores `#pragma`?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I had read that many stuff about pragmas are compiler dependant,but never knew the preprocessor doesn't process pragmas at all.Is it so?

Comment: Well I know that using something like:
    `#define FOO parallel`
    `#pragma omp FOO`
Will work as:
    `#pragma omp parallel`

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I had read in a book that there are broadly 4 types of pre-processor directives 1)Macros 2)File Inclusion, 3)Conditional compilation and 4)Miscellaneous pre-processor directives like `#undef` and `#pragma`.So Mr.Pileborg,can you confirm that `#pragma` is **NOT** a pre-processor directive as your comment seems to suggest?

Comment: I did some experimentation, and it seems that _arguments_ to a pragma can contain contain macro calls, but not the actual pragma _command_. I don't have a C specification, but will check the C++ specification and see what that says.

Comment: You could perhaps use `_Pragma` not `#pragma`

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Can you please tell what you mean by `I don't think the preprocessor processes pragmas`?Isn't `#pragma` a pre-processor directive?

Comment: @Rüppell'sVulture In C++ `#pragma` is indeed a preprocessor directive, but it doesn't specify anything else really.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Maybe I don't understand it correctly, but wouldn't using `_Pragma` only allow me to define something to replace `_Pragma`? e.g. `#define FOO(x) _Pragma(#x)` `FOO(omp parallel)` would be equivalent to `_Pragma("omp parallel")` or `#pragma omp parallel`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since C99 we have the `_Pragma` operator, that basically allows you to place the contents of `#pragma` everywhere, not only on a line of its own, and to have it subject to macro expansion. Something like

```
#define STRINGIFY_(...) #__VA_ARGS__
#define STRINGIFY(...) STRINGIFY_(__VA_ARGS__)
#define FOO omp
#define PARALLEL(...) _Pragma(STRINGIFY(FOO parallel __VA_ARGS__))
```

and then

```
PARALLEL(private(a))
for(size_t i = 0; i < NUM; ++i)
  ....
```

should do the trick.

If you are just interested in using such stuff (compared to writing these macros) you could use [P99 preprocessor blocks](http://p99.gforge.inria.fr/p99-html/group__preprocessor__blocks.html) that implements things like `P99_PARALLEL_FOR` and `P99_PARALLEL_FORALL` with these kind of tricks.

Comment: I tried this and a few variations of it, but the line still ends up being interpreted as `#pragma FOO parallel`

Comment: @Chris, ah sorry, you'd have to do one more level of macro expansion, please see my edit.

Comment: For me that ends up interpreted as: `#pragma "FOO parallel __VA_ARG__"
` Are you compiling with gcc?

Comment: Yes, gcc v. 4.6. Using this (with a correction on the `__VA_ARGS__`, sorry) and `-std=c99 -fopenmp` works without problems. Also when using clang as a compiler it tells me `<scratch space>:3:2: note: expanded from macro '_Pragma'
 omp parallel private (a)`

Comment: For me, it ends up interpreted as `#pragma "FOO parallel private(a)"` I am using gcc v. 4.4, so I'm guessing that this is the reason for me getting different results from you. I guess what I want to do won't be possible with gcc v. 4.4, and I will have to find another solution. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: Bizarre, I don't think that the preprocessing phase of gcc changed much in the last years. You are sure that you copied the code as it stands now?

Comment: Ah, ok got it finally. I had `#define STRINGIFY(X) STRINGIFY_(#X)` instead of `#define STRINGIFY(X) STRINGIFY_(X)` I can't believe I missed that. Why is the second level of macro expansion for stringify needed?

Comment: The `#` operator is designed that it stringifies its argument without expansion, such that you might really see in a string what you passed as an argument to a macro. When processing a macro, only the arguments to that macro are expanded, so on the first level only `__VA_ARGS__` is expanded and not `FOO`. For stringify, then, all is argument and that is expanded, and so now the `FOO` that is part of it.

Comment: @Chris, note that I now also changed to use `...` everywhere, such that the macro would even work if the arguments contain commas at some point.

Answer (score 0):

There was gcc developer discussion about a patch that accepted a "-fexpand-pragmas" command-line option in 2006:

http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-patches/2006-10/msg00084.html

but that option does not appear to be recognized